# setting Ooyala videos to be HTML 5 by default

Tags: javascript, html5-video, ooyala

I want to set up v3 of Ooayla's api and use html 5 videos. So far I've followed the instructions here  and I've added to the players js script to include the parameters to force html video. The video won't show  on chrome for android 4.4 and on desktop it reverts to flash. If I say html only then it doesn't show up at all on either devices.

Here's my header code

```
<script src='https://player.ooyala.com/v3/MWI3YjYwYTBiZjg1ZWE0ZTYyZWViM2Ew?platform=html5-priority'></script>
```

My javascript code

```
//topVideo.field_ooyala_upload is the variable for the video id.     

   OO.ready(function() { 
          window.player = OO.Player.create(
            'playerwrapper',
            topVideo.field_ooyala_upload, {
              // add the embedded player parameters here
              autoplay: false
            }
          );
        });
```

Not sure why I can't get HTML5 videos to show up. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To stream using HTML5 V3 Player you have to add the ULR query param as you have done correctly.
Note that this will stream using progressive download on both desktop and Android and as such this encoding must be enabled in your account.

If you want to try HLS streaming, and have that encoding enabled, for Android you have to enable an additional query string parameter described [here](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/concepts/player_v3dev_hls_android.html).

If you have a more complete sample of your code, please share it for further comments.